# How to get html contents more specific

Tags: php, html

i need some help.
i want to get html content on test.php

```
<p> This is content on paragraph or article on web page</p>
<p>[albumname=Mount Climbing]</p>
```

i want to process those [albumname] to be a thumbnails of picture .
this is my flow :
-  Get the parameter of albumname . I want query that album name on db and fetch    the picture (i know how to do this)
- After querying it,i want to replace [albumname="parameter"] with thumbnails

The point is :
- how to get [albumname=Mount Climbing] to be expanded using variable.
$album = this will be "Mount Climbing"

need help :(

Comment: Are you using WordPress, or straight PHP / MySQL?

Comment: i am using straight PHP

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm the author. I've written a small library to enable shortcode functionality outside of a Wordpress environment. See if it can help: [maiorano84/shortcodes](https://github.com/maiorano84/shortcodes)

Comment: @maiorano84 do i need all your files to using it ? if yes,i just wanna use my files.because i am already write many files :(

Comment: @mrezzaaa21 Yes. It's a library that is intended to take a string using the shortcode format you're using and unroll it using a server side callback. This kind of behavior is not native to PHP or HTML, but rather something popularized by Wordpress, which was why Jonathan asked if you were using it. Do you already have this behavior implemented somewhere in your own file structure? If so, can you clarify exactly where you're having trouble? If not, then I'm not sure why the number of files would be an issue (as this is a comparatively small library)

Comment: hmmmm
i just need like a ereg_replace .but if i using it the parameter cannot be processed,so i need to know how to get/find html content based on keyword .maybe

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use the entire library, [try using this as a starting point](https://github.com/maiorano84/shortcodes/blob/master/src/Parsers/DefaultParser.php). That's the same regular expression Wordpress uses, so based off of that, you can probably roll your own stripped down version.

Comment: @maiorano84 okay,thanks before man :)

Comment: Were you looking for something like this:

`$s = "[albumname=Mount Climbing]";
$len   = strlen( "[albumname=" );
$end   = strpos ( $s, "]" );
$name   = substr( $s, $len, $end ); //11 is length of [albumname=
`

Comment: @user3633383no,that albumname parameter will by dinamic.i've founded the way with my own :) .Thanks bro

Comment: FYI `ereg_` family of functions is deprecated in PHP and has been for quite a while. Why do you worry about the number of files in a library?

Answer (score 0):

I've found my way like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents("test.php");
preg_match_all("/\[\w+\=\w+\s+\w+]/", $html, $matches);
```

And I use `var_dump($matches)` to look at the string I want to process more after that.

Comment: Any reason why you require a whitespace in your data? You do realize that `[gallery=foobar]` wouldn't work with that regular expression? `[gallery=foo bar baz]` wouldn't work either, only things like `[gallery=foo bar]` would work with this.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the review of my code. i've been updated with this one

```
preg_match_all("/\[\w*\=\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*]", $html, $matches);
```

to more dynamicly :)